# How do you define a time datatype when creating tables in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

How do I resolve this error, ORA-00907?

Comment: Post text, not images of text.

Comment: type code here.

Comment: **Never** store date/time values (`Shift_Day Char(3)`) as strings. Use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATE`. In Oracle, it contains both date and time. There's no datatype just for time.

A suggestion, if I may: as there's no `TIME` datatype and if you planned to use `VARCHAR2` datatype and store "time" values, don't do that. Although most of values will probably be OK (e.g. 07:25:13), sooner or later someone will enter something like 58:2f:x7 which certainly isn't valid time). Therefore, do use `DATE`.

Comment: and shift_day could be a virtual column derived from the shift_time...